# How to use HashMap and print out the value of an HashMap in an HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

This is my Qode:

```
    vehicle SMH9296 = new vehicle("car", "S MH 9296", 0, 0);

    HashMap <Integer, Object> HashMapLevel = new HashMap <Integer, Object>()
    HashMap <Integer, vehicle> HashMapSlot = new HashMap <Integer, vehicle>();
    HashMapSlot.put(1, SMH9296);    

    HashMapLevel.put(0, HashMapSlot);

    for (Object i : HashMapLevel.values()) {
        for (vehicle vehicle : i.values()) { //here is the Problem
            System.out.println(vehicle.getLicencePlate());
        }
    }
```

The Error is: The method values() is undefined for the type Object

But my Object should be a vehicle and i should be able to get the values like that.

I dont understand why this doesnt work.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea1')
var email = document.getElementById('email')

function updateText() {
  email.value = textarea.value
}

textarea.addEventListener('input', updateText)

// At start...
updateText()
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend> Mail </legend>

  <form action="" method="post">
    Enter your comments here: <br />
    <textarea id="textarea1" rows="30" cols="50">hallo</textarea> <br />

    Your Email here:
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
    <input type="reset" value="reset form">
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

NB: don't forget the "" around your HTML attribute values (even if it is JS code)